# Display current branch name on every `git log` line

Tags: git

If I create a commit with Git, it provides a simple log message with the branch name, short SHA and a one line description:

```
[branchname 481f23b] Fixes from code review
```

But if I use `git log --oneline`, I only get short SHAs and subjects:

```
481f23b Fixes from code review
bb4070e Merge branch 'update-docs' into 'master'
e0095b2 Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/master' into HEAD
```

I can't work out any way to use `git log --format="format:..."` to print out the current branch name on every line.

For example, if I use `--format="format:[%D %h] %s"`:

```
[HEAD -> branchname, origin/branchname 481f23b] Fixes from code review
[ bb4070e] Merge branch 'update-docs' into 'master'
[ e0095b2] Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/master' into HEAD
```

Is there any way to configure `git log` to display the (current) branch name on every log line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a bit of shell hackery, it seems I can emulate this with `sed` and bash substitution:

```
git log -200 --format="format:%Cgreen[BRANCHNAME %h]%Creset %s" | (sed "s/BRANCHNAME/$(git symbolic-ref -q --short HEAD || git describe --tags --exact-match)/")
```

Of course, this will display every single commit is now "part" of this branch, even if it wasn't originally.

Comment: See torek's illuminating answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your shell trick will work, though I'd simply get the branch name first (into a shell variable) and then use that directly in the `--format` line.

There's a good reason git doesn't do this, though: commits are not so much "on **a** branch" as "contained in some **set** of branches".  For instance:

```
...--o--A--B--C     <-- branch1
      \
       D--E         <-- branch2
```

Obviously commits `A` through `C` are "on" `branch1` and `D` and `E` are "on" `branch2`.  But then let's do a `git merge branch2` while we're on `branch1`:

```
...--o--A--B--C     <-- branch1
      \        \
       D--E-----M   <-- branch2
```

Now commits `A` through `C` are on branch2, too.

Now let's use `git branch -d branch1` to remove the label `branch1`, which is safe since it's merged into `branch2`:

```
...--o--A--B--C
      \        \
       D--E-----M   <-- branch2
```

Nothing has changed, but now `A` through `C` are only "on" `branch2` since `branch1` is gone.

The commit graph is fixed (because commits *are*, in a fairly deep sense, their SHA-1s: if you change anything, including parent IDs, commit messages, or timestamps, you get a new, different commit, even if the source tree attached to that commit is the same).  The branch labels, though, are ephemeral: they move, change, or even disappear entirely, without changing the graph.

In any case, a single commit can be "on" more than one branch.  Any given branch label points to a single commit, but that commit can point back to multiple previous commits.  A merge commit is defined as a commit pointing to at least two parents, and as such it causes those commits to be contained within the branch, even when—as is normal during development—at least some of those commits have another label pointing to them, or pointing to something that points to them.

You don't even need merges to get this effect: just create a new branch that points to some existing commit.  For instance, before deleting `branch1`, even before merging, create a new label `branch3` also pointing to commit `C`:

```
...--o--A--B--C     <-- branch1, branch3
      \
       D--E         <-- branch2
```

Now commits `A` through `C` are on *two* branches, and when you merge branch1 into branch3, they'll be on *three* branches.

Comment: "branch": the most misleading Git term.